# Not able to get the call back notifications for a new oAuth2.0 user from Fitbit

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, fitbit

As part of Fitbit Oauth2.0 migration, we have changed our java code according to support Oauth2. We are able to connect the device and able to get the access token and refresh token. And also we have saved the new refresh token to get the new access token every time for both new user and migrated user.

Issue: When we try to add a manual entry in fitbit, we are able to get the call back notification for a migrated member(OAuth1.0 to OAuth2.0). But when we added entry for a new user(Connected using OAuth2.0), we are not able to receive the call back notifications.

We ensured that the application notification is enabled.

We searched in the Forum and found all about text, call vibrate notifications etc.. but not the call back notification.

Can any one help us what we are missing.

Comment: I didn't know Fitbit had an API. Thanks for the info! Also, adding a fitbit tag might help